# Rearranging display of Date Field in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser, date

Can you rearrange the text in date field type in ArcGIS?

Eg. Map_Date - 05/30/2014 (I want to reformat this to 2014-05-30)

I've been trying to use the field calculator on all my records, but cannot figure out the syntax for either Python or VB.

Comment: Do you want to change the actual data in your featureclass, or just how dates are displayed in ArcGIS? For the latter, see here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163276/labeling-with-two-decimal-places-rounded-even-when-second-is-zero-in-arcmap/185205#185205

Comment: change how they are displayed

Comment: My bad, that solution works only for numeric fields, not dates.

Comment: can I change the date field to a string or number in that same format?

Comment: The date format used by ArcMap is conform your system settings, search the ArcGIS Desktop help for *Changing the way ArcMap displays short format dates in Windows 7*.

Answer (score 1):

This is copied verbatim from the ArcGIS Desktop help. The instructions are for Windows 7, so it's probably different for newer versions. You get the idea, though.

> **Changing the way ArcMap displays short format dates in Windows 7**
>
> You can change the way ArcMap displays date formats by setting date
> format options within the Regional and Language settings of your
> computer.
>
> Steps:
>
> 1. Click the **Start** button in Windows 7.
> 2. Click **Control Panel**.
> 3. Click **Region and Language**.
> 4. Click the **Formats** tab.
> 5. Click the **Short date format** drop-down arrow and click the desired date format.
> 6. Click **OK**.