# Calculating between today's date and date field in attribute table ofArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, date, differences

I am trying to use DateDiff to calculate the difference between today's date and the initiated date of various projects. I created a new field called "Duration of Day" and I tried the calculation: DateDiff("d", [INITATIEDATE], Now()) , this however keeps coming up as an error and will not work.

How do I make this calculation work in ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: seems arcmaps field calculator (guessing). Here are the help docs. be sure your date fields are formatted correctly as well . http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculating-an-attribute-to-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates.htm

Comment: Using ArcMap 10.4.1. Trying the calculation in the field calculator using VB Script. I'm open to using python script but I am not really familiar with that way.

Comment: intialdate field is formatted as a date field correct?

Comment: yes initated date is formatted as a date field. it's formatted like yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z

Comment: and how is the new field formatted? same way?

Comment: No. I thought if I'm finding the duration of day between present date it should be a number right? Say the initatied date was exactly a week from today, then I would want the duration of day to be "7" in the attribute table. Or can it not work that way? (Fairly new to arcgis)

Comment: No you're right if the goal is to capture only #days. I think the way your intital date field is formatted is causing it to error. BTW I forgot, what errors are you seeing or whats the output after executing?

Comment: Now() returns a date and time. Try CDate(Now()) to just get the date part

Comment: It says I have an error executing function 999999 "this is a generic error for which the cause does not have a specific error ID"

Comment: I tried CDate(Now()) and it still does not work, comes with the same error

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this out using your script above on my own data and it worked.
However my original_date field is formatted "MM/DD/YYYY".
the above VBS Script succeeded in calculating the duration of days from current date.

Reformat your date field to use the above format. 
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-date-fields.htm

Comment: How do I reformat dates in arcmap?

Comment: few ways you can do this, you can use slicing(indexing) to place the index in the order you want with python, or you can try the method I linked, I have not tried this but it may work https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202838/how-to-rearrange-the-value-of-a-date-field-in-arcgis-05-30-2014-2014-05-30